# Почему в слове "семей" нулевое окончание?

Tags: грамматика

Почему в слове *семей* (*семья*, р.п., мн. ч.) нулевое окончание? Выглядит будто окончание здесь *ей*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему в слове семей (семья, р.п., мн. ч.) нулевое окончание? Выглядит будто окончание здесь ей.

"Выглядит" - это субъективно...
Вообще, конечно, можно спорить, что считать окончанием...
Но давайте разберем логику тех, кто считает "семей" корнем - с беглым гласным между "м" и "й".

Сравним окончания при склонении слов по двум типам, например, *баня, пуля* и  *тень, лошадь*. "Семья", "полынья", "шея" и подобные должны склоняться по одному из двух указанных типов.

И. бан**я**, пул**я**, тень, лошадь
...
И. бан**и**, пул**и**, тен**и**, лошад**и**
Р. бань, пуль, тен**ей**, лошад**ей**
Д. бан**ям**, пул**ям**, тен**ям**, лошад**ям**
... 
(и т.д. - можете продолжить).

И посмотрим на склонение (и его фонетическую запись) наших слов. Условная (приблизительная) транскрипция ниже дается только для последних звуков.

И. Семья [сем'й**а**] , полынья [полын'й**а**], шея [шей**а**]
...
И. Семьи [сем'(й)**и**] , полыней [полын'(й)**и**], шея [ше(й)**и**]
Р. Семей [семей] , полыней [полыней], шей [шей]
Д. Семьям [сем'(й)**ам**] , полыньям [полын'(й)**ам**], шеям [ше(й)**ам**]
...

По-моему - более чем убедительно. "Семьи" склоняются по типу "бань" или "пуль", никак не по типу "теней" или "лошадей". Т.е. окончание в родительном множественного - нулевое.
Конечно, тут можно и по-другому рассуждать, полагая, что у слов на "-ья" особая парадигма склонения. Поэтому вопрос остается дискуссионным. Но уж во всяком случае говорить об очевидности окончания "ей" никак нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Семья (И.п. ед.ч.) – семьи (И.п. мн.ч.) – семей (Р.п. мн.ч.). Здесь нулевое окончание (Е – беглое).

Существительные в форме Р.п. мн. числа могут иметь окончания ОВ/ЕВ, ЕЙ  и нулевое. Существует правило:  **если в начальной форме окончание ненулевое, то в форме Р.п. мн. числа  окончание   нулевое, и наоборот: семь-я  (ненулевое) – семей (нулевое).**

Сравнить: лист (нулевое) – листья – листь-ев (ненулевое).

Answer (score 1):

Сравните: улица – улиц, лица – лиц, господа – господ, ямы – ям и т.д. Нулевое окончание здесь несомненно. А семьи – сем[ь, й, ей]. "Ей" здесь обусловлено фонетикой, а не морфемикой – так легче произносить. И нет причин считать его окончанием.

Answer (score 1):

Окончание у существительных находится **изменением слова по падежам.**

В слове ***семья*** звук [й'], скрывающийся в букве ***я***, относится не к окончанию, а к основе, **т. к. он сохраняется при склонении этого слова:**
сем'[й'/а],  сем'[й'/и], сем'[й'/э], сем'[й'/у] и т. д.

Во мн. числе:
сем'[й'/и],  **сем'[эй'/#] (в основе появился беглый [э], окончание пропало)**, сем'[й'/ам], сем'[й'/и] и т. д.

**P.S.** А правила *"если в начальной форме окончание ненулевое, то в форме Р.п. мн. числа окончание нулевое, и наоборот",* по-моему, просто не может существовать (хоть для большей части существительных эта формула и справедлива).

Ведь если бы оно существовало, то и в формах родительного падежа мн. ч. таких, к примеру, слов,  как ***тля, ханжа, доля, ноздря, вожжа, поле, море*** и многих других пришлось бы выделять нулевое окончание. Ан нет --  в  род. п. мн. ч. у этих слов  всё-таки  окончание не нулевое, а ***"-ей".***

Comment: Слава, правило о соотношении окончаний - это эмпирическое правило, или правило-наблюдение. Оно ничего не назначает, но определяет существующую общую тенденцию, и им удобно пользоваться в том случае, если в речи существуют парные варианты окончаний (основные и вариантные, нормированные и ненормированные). Из приведенного списка    возможен только фонетический вариант основного нулевого окончания "доль", но он является ненормированным. Также возможно неправильное ударение "дОлей". Поэтому это слово рассматривается в орфоэпических словарях.

Comment: Vera, сказать по правде, ни-че-го не понял из комментария... Каюсь!

Comment: Как это ничего! Тогда я еще кратенько объясню. Вы должны забыть это правило и смело говорить "поле - полей и море - морей". Применять его надо только при необходимости. Например, нельзя сказать "килограмм апельсин и яблоков". А если вас спросят "почему это?", то вы грамотно ответите: для названий фруктов и овощей используются исключительно основные окончания: м.р. - ОВ и ж.р. - нулевое. Вашим оппонентам нечего будет возразить.

Comment: Например, нельзя сказать "килограмм апельсин"… Сказать-то можно (см. http://rusgram.narod.ru/1194-1215.html ): " В разговорной речи формы род. п. с нулевой флексией употребительны у слов – названий овощей и плодов: абрикосы – абрикос, апельсины – апельсин… В письменной речи употребление форм род. п. с нулевой флексией у перечисленных слов не рекомендуется".

Comment: Помимо "Русской грамматики" оппоненты смогут сослаться и на Горбачевича (http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/gorbachevich-90.htm ):
"Долгое время велись ожесточенные споры относительно правильности форм родительного падежа множественного числа: грамм, апельсин, помидор... Социологическое обследование показало, что подавляющее большинство, независимо от возраста и профессии, употребляют сейчас именно бракуемые грамматиками формы без окончания -ов. При обработке магнитофонных записей выяснилось: из 400 информантов 394 человека сказали килограмм помидор и только четверо - помидоров".

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос об основе слов с разделительным Ь объяснял ещё Ломоносов :

> М. В. Ломоносов. Российская грамматика (1755)
> Стоящая ь перед я переменяется на е, а я ― на й краткое: бадья, бадей; келья, келей; лодья, лодей; оладья, оладей; попадья, попадей; скамья, скамей; свинья, свиней; тафья, тафей; тулья, тулей.

Основа с конечным звуком **j** легко проверяется. Семья - семейКа, скамья - скамейКа, келья - келейНый, ладья - ладейНый, скуфья - скуфейКа и тд.
В существительных типа фея, рея, лотерея проверка точно такая же : лотерейНый.

Правило.

> (Множественное число) В Р. п. у существительных могут быть представлены окончания: **нулевое**, -ов, -ей.
> I скл.: основное окончание — **нулевое**: стран-, деревень-.
> У слов с основой на j перед j появляется беглая гласная е, если ударение в И.п падает на окончание (скамья — скамей-) и гласная и, если на основу (гостья — гостий-).
> Отдельные слова образуют Р. п. окончанием -ей: свеч-ей, дяд-ей, пригоршн-ей.

О словах II скл. на **-ие/ье** - ниже в комментарии.

Comment: А как объяснить: листья - листьев (окончание ЕВ), ожерелье - ожерелий (нулевое окончание)?

Comment: По ожерелью, Vera)  
>Множественное число
От некоторых существительных среднего рода множественное число образуется с помощью окончания -и :  яблоко — яблоки, ухо — уши, плечо — плечи.
Родительный падеж
1. Существительные на -ие (приглашение, издание) и на -ье (**ожерелье, предместье, побережье**) оканчиваются на -ий : приглашений, изданий, заданий, ожерелий, предместий, побережий.
2. Существительные на -ьё оканчиваются на -ей: ружьё - ружей.
Исключение: копьё - копий.
3. Слова низовье, устье, платье имеют окончание -ев: низовьев, устьев, платьев.

Comment: Ну да, всё правильно,  для существительных  на ЕЙ/ИЙ в  форме  Р.п. мн. числа возможны следующие варианты: 1) решение – решений (нулевое  окончание); 2) ожерелье - ожерелий(нулевое окончание, беглая гласная И);  3)семья – семей (нулевое окончание, беглая гласная Е); 4) акварель – акварелей  (ненулевое окончание ЕЙ).

Comment: Труден русский язык. Решениjев, ожерелиjев...

Comment: Решениjев, ожерелиjев - нельзя. Средний род, нулевое окончание является основным, нет причин нарушать правила.